# Selected polygon from VectorTile isn't stylized

Tags: javascript, openlayers, vector-tiles

I'm be able to see a selected polygon on the map using the code below:

```
  const layer = 'test2:project_subareaurban_polygon_8';
  const projection_epsg_no = '3857';
  const vectortile_layer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    declutter: true,
    opacity: 0.75,
    source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
      format: new ol.format.MVT({featureClass: ol.Feature}),
      url: 'http://localhost:8600/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/' + layer +
            '@EPSG%3A'+projection_epsg_no+'@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf'
    }),
  });
  map.addLayer(vectortile_layer);
  const highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255,0,255,1.0)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)',
      width: 2
    })
  });

  let selected = null;
  map.on('singleclick', function(e) {
    if (selected !== null) {
      selected.setStyle(undefined);
      selected = null;
    }

    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(f) {
      selected = f;
      f.setStyle(highlightStyle);
      vectortile_layer.changed();
      return true;
    });

  });
```

But when I use `ol.interaction.Select` I can see the selected polygon only if I use zoom-in/zoom-out

```
  const layer = 'test2:project_subareaurban_polygon_8';
  const projection_epsg_no = '3857';
  const vectortile_layer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    declutter: true,
    opacity: 0.75,
    source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
      format: new ol.format.MVT({featureClass: ol.Feature}),
      url: 'http://localhost:8600/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/' + layer +
            '@EPSG%3A'+projection_epsg_no+'@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf'
    }),
  });
  map.addLayer(vectortile_layer);
  const highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255,0,255,1.0)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)',
      width: 2
    })
  });

  const selectGeometry = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.singleClick,
    layers: [vectortile_layer],
    style: highlightStyle,
  });

  let selectedFeatureID;
  let selected = null;
  function activeSelection() {
    map.addInteraction(selectGeometry);

    selectGeometry.getFeatures().on('add', function (event) {
      let properties = event.element.getProperties();
      selectedFeatureID = properties.fid;

    });
  };
```

It is no clear for me how I can solve this problem. What I doing wrong?

Comment: The first sample calls `vectortile_layer.changed();`  You may also need that  in the `selectGeometry.getFeatures().on('add'` function in the second sample.

Comment: Thank you @Mike but is not clear for me what do you mean. Please, can you add a more detailed answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use vectortile_layer.changed() to force a render of the layer in the first sample (because changing a feature on a tile does not cause a layer change event?) you will probably alsi need it in the second sample

```
selectGeometry.getFeatures().on('add', function (event) {
  let properties = event.element.getProperties();
  selectedFeatureID = properties.fid;
  vectortile_layer.changed();
});
```

Comment: Ok, now I understand. I've already tested this without fortune :(

Comment: Solved, thanks @Mike
The problem was the OL version of my project. The right version for use `changed()` method is 6.6.1, I was using the 6.3.1